# Problem with FOR loop syntax in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to count the records per minute of a date in a table column. With the following query, I can do it:

```
select count(tableSmol.date) from tableSmol as tableSmol 
--take part of the year (2020)
where date_part('year', tableSmol.date) = 2020 
--take part of the mounth (06)
and date_part('month',tableSmol.date) = 6
--take part of the day (02)
and date_part('day', tableSmol.date) = 02 
--take part of the hour (16 hurs)
and date_part('hour',tableSmol.date) = 16
--take part of the minutes (07 minutes)
and date_part('minute', tableSmol.date) = 07
```

But in the previous query I can only count the records for a specific minute, what I need to do is a count of all the records of all the minutes from June 2020 to June 2021. I have tried with the below code, but the syntax is bad and I don't know what I'm failing at. I would appreciate your help.

```
Do
$do$
declare  iMinute int := 0;
         iHour int := 0;
         iDay int := 1;
         iMonth int := 1;
         iYear int := 2020;
        
         totalMinute int := 59;
         totalHour int := 23;
         totalDay int := 28;
         totalMonth int := 12;
         totalYear int := 2021;
begin       
    select count(tableSmol.date) from tableSmol as tableSmol
    where tableSmol.date notnull 
    for iYear in 1..totalYear
    loop 
        and date_part('year', tableSmol.date) = iYear 
        for iMonth in 1..totalMonth
        loop 
            and date_part('month', tableSmol.date) = iMonth 
            for iDay in 1..totalDay
            loop 
                and date_part('day', tableSmol.date) = iDay
                for iHour in 1..totalHour
                loop 
                    and date_part('hour', tableSmol.date) = iHour
                    for iMinute in 1..totalMinute
                    loop 
                        and date_part('minute', tableSmol.date) = iMinute
                        Raise notice 'Total: %',iMinute;
                    end loop;
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end loop;       
end 
$do$;
```

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site, and either translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on [es.so]

Comment: Before going any further I would suggest you look at [FOR over query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add conditions to a `WHERE` clause like that. You'd need dynamic SQL to do that. But dynamic SQL is tricky and not needed as it seems you simply want to filter by a range of time. You can simply use `>=` and `<` for that.

```
SELECT count(date)
       FROM tablesmol
       WHERE date >= '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::timespamp -- or whatever you start time is (there are three different ones in your post, so I don't know the right one)
             AND date < concat(     totalyear,
                               '-', totalmonth,
                               '-', totalday,
                               ' ', totalhour,
                               ':', totalminute,
                               ':00')::timestamp
                        + '1 minute'::interval;
```

This is also preferable as it can use indexes on `date` whereas using a function on `date` removes that possibility (unless the exact function call is indexed as well (but there's no need here to make things more complicated than necessary)). If indexes can be used that can significantly speed up query execution.